# can this spam poster be dealt with soon

Tags: support, status-completed, spam

https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35196/user2657067

This user has posted 3 times in the last 5 mins.  I would hate to see what happens if we wait too long.

So this person seems to be upset with SO for suspending him/her:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2657067/user2657067

[image]

If someone is suspended on one site, should maybe they be suspended every where to prevent revenge defacing of other sites?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've destroyed their account: spam usually gets very short shrift.

Comment: Apparently this user is angry with SO.  Do you think they should be notified of his/her behavior since they are suspended?

Comment: @dustin The content really did just look like spam so I'm not sure it's a 'real' account at all. I'll see what's come up in the mod-only chat.

Comment: I checked his/her post at SO and they are real post.  So unless someone hacked his/her account, they were just upset.

Comment: @dustin Unrelated Sorry, BTW is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18206/dustin) your's

Comment: @texenthusiast not me.